# Bind - resolving hostname to wired and wireless IP addresses

Tags: networking, dns, bind

I've set up Bind on Ubuntu server to act as a DNS server on the home network. It seems to be working fine. I can load the default Apache page using the fqdn I specified in the zone forwarding file and all my clients ping each other using the hostnames specified in Bind.

But, we have four laptops in the house - all with Ethernet and WiFi connections. I want to able to resolve laptop's hostnames to either the wired or the wireless IP addresses.

Every device in the house, including these laptops, has a static IP address for both its wired and wireless connection. Ideally, in the first instance the local DNS server would query the wired Ethernet connection. If it wasn't available, it would then try and resolve the host name to the IP address associated with the laptop's WiFi adapter.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have the same nerwork range for eth and wless.
You can use the same ip address on both interfaces and make one record on dns server.
Down side of this proposition is you can not be, in the same time, connected with boot interfaces.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know you could do that. If possible, I'd rather have both wired and wireless interfaces able to connect at the same time. But if that proves not to be possible, I'll definitely go with your solution. Thanks again!